# How to change get_the_post_thumbnail_url output with filter or raw php

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, action

This is my question:

I want to change the output of this function:

```
$thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
```

The URL will return something like:

```
http://mywebsite.local/wp-content/uploads/myimage.png
```

My goal is just to change the first part of the URL with something like:

```
http://myurl.local/wp-content/uploads/myimage.png
```

I can always use str_replace:

```
$otherthumb = str_replace('http://mywebsite.local', 'http://myurl.local', $thumb);
```

But I was hoping to find something already baked.

Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use wordpress [wp_get_attachment_image_src](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) filter hook.

```
function change_image_url( $image, $attachment_id, $size, $icon ){
    $otherthumb = str_replace('http://mywebsite.local', 'http://myurl.local', $image[0]);
    return $otherthumb;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_src', 'change_image_url', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Essentially, I will wrap the link inside a function and then I will add the filter?

Comment: Yes, but this filter in your activated theme functions.php and change your URL.